# Как найти проверить в столбце в файле csv?

Tags: python, csv

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить(не найти) наличия id в столбце?
В моем примере я получаю кучу результатов `есть`, а мне нужно добиться результата чтобы результат вернулся один `есть` или `нету`.

```
with open('bd/db.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if user.id not in row:
            print('Есть')
        else:
            print('Нету')
```

Comment: Вопрос только в уменьшении количества "Есть" (тогда см. код в ответе) или он сложнее?

Comment: Спасибо всем. Я разобрался

Comment: @MaxWatson, пожалуйста, и не забудьте отметить понравившиеся ответы и принять тот, что помог с проблемой :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно флаг завести:

```
with open('bd/db.csv') as csvfile:
    found = False
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if user.id in row:
            found = True
            break

    print('Есть' if found else 'Нету')
```

Comment: а зачем? Лишний флаг, лишние строчки? Почему не просто break? В С я бы так, как вы делал, но Python всё про минимизацию говорит...

Comment: @Сергей, есть разница у меня гарантировано выведет что-то одно, а не на каждую строку :)

Comment: ясно, спасибо, я просто отработал только, что написали, что много "есть". Много "нет" не рассматривал. Зря, наверное:-)

Answer (score 1):

break должен помочь получить один "Есть".

```
with open('bd/db.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if user.id not in row:
            print('Есть')
            break 
        else:
            print('Нету')
```